# Can i use Tailwind CSS and Material UI in the same Next js project?

Tags: material-ui, next.js, tailwind-css

If I used both of them, could I run into conflicts? Is this a good approach to use?

Comment: Yes you can, tailwind allows adding prefix to your classes, so with proper configuration, it is likely that you'll never run into conflicts. For your second question, StackOverflow is really not the platform to ask that as its opinion-based. Some people actually do use utility frameworks with component frameworks, but it is just a choice - the one you need to make yourself, maybe after asking for experiences on forums like Reddit.

Answer (score 26):

It is possible and the MUI team has resolved it.

From the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css):

> If you are used to Tailwind CSS and want to use it together with the MUI components, you can start by cloning the [Tailwind CSS example](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/tailwind-css) project. If you use a different framework or already have set up your project.

It is necessary to Remove Tailwind's base directive in favor of the CssBaseline component provided by `@mui/material` and fix the CSS injection order.

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-ui-cra-tailwind-ts

Answer (score 7):

You can use Base UI instead of Material UI.
https://mui.com/base/guides/working-with-tailwind-css/

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can run both ui framework. But it is not a good approach. Every ui framework has the complete solution for designing ui part. Like in tailwind css you can have the JIT compiler for compilation your custom css. Or the other hand MUI has also.

I think you can go through just only on ui framework. I have suggestion for ui. For your next js project you can use-
Tailwind Css
Theme-ui

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, You will be in a big problem because once you initialize a styling library it applies its basic styles to the components so that if you are using more than one styling library you may not be able to change the behavior or styles of the components.

It also leads to rubbish suggestions while adding classes names and so on.
Stick to a UI libray and go with it.If you cant get it using the ui libraray do it yourself using CSS that could be more interesting and you can have more control over the components.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using Mui and Tailwindcss together and it's not worth it. First, you will have to use `Mui/base` instead of `Mui/material` in order to reduce conflicts check https://mui.com/base/guides/working-with-tailwind-css. And if you really need to customize Mui components `styled` of the `sx` prop. This is just my opinion.

Comment: I tried to turn your post into an answer. But if you meant it as a comment, e.g. on https://stackoverflow.com/a/73739448/7733418 then please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead and either [edit] this into an answer according to [aswer] or delete it.

Comment: It's not entirely accurate. Here's [an example of Taiwlind + MUI that's using `@mui/material`]. It's worked great without the mess of `{{}}` and `sx`. Perhaps consult here.

Answer (score 0):

You can [disable the preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight) from tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```

It will remove all the default styles of tailwind CSS and it will not clash with MUI components styles.

You may sometimes face problems in applying tailwind styles because of MUI's default styling but you can solve them by trying different values.

for example, you will need to provide `border border-solid` classes instead of writing `border` only.

I hope it will work.